# Are these two that-clauses complements for the same verb?

Tags: complements

> To believe ***that*** there’s order and I have a place in it, is just
>   too scary, ***that*** if I’m not here doing what I’m supposed to do,
>   nothing else will be right. ([Kathy Holwadel](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/15305/))

There are two that-clauses. Are both the complements for *believe*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think so.  The two that-clauses are coordinated, but there's no overt coordinator such as *and*, so this is an example of *asyndetic coordination*.